# R ddply ignores split factors when column index is used

Tags: r, indexing, grouping, multiple-columns, plyr

I need to to use ddply to apply multiple functions on multiple columns of my data frame. When I use the column name (RV in the example below), my split variables (Group and Round below) work (I get a mean value for each combination of Round and Group).

I need to do this on 20 columns and I was thinking of creating a for loop and pass column indexes.

When I use the column index (for example  df[[1]]  which is "RV" in my data frame), Group and Round are ignored and the grand mean is returned for all combinations of Round and Group.

I tried to pass the column name, in new.df3 but Round and Group are ignored again.

```
df <- data.frame("RV" = 1:5, "Group" = c("a","b","b","b","a"), "Round" = c("2","1","1","2","1"))

# this works and a separate mean for each combination of "Group" and "Round" is calculated 
new.df <- ddply(df, c("Group", "Round"), summarise,
            mean= mean(RV))

# this does not work and the grand mean is returned for all combinations of "Group" and "Round" 
new.df2 <- ddply(df, c("Group", "Round"), summarise,
            mean= mean(df[[1]]))

# this does not work and the grand mean is returned for all combinations of "Group" and "Round"     
new.df3 <- ddply(df, c("Group", "Round"), summarise,
             mean= mean(df[,colnames(df[1])]))
```

I tried "lapply" and the same issue exists. Any suggestion why this happens and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

As great a package as `plyr` is, you would do well here to update to it's newest iteration, `dplyr`.  There, the code would be

```
v <- vars(RV) # add all your variables here
new.df <- df %>%
  group_by(Group, Round) %>%
  summarize_at(v, funs(mean))
```

So using this method, you plug in all your variables into `v`, and you'll get a mean for all of them, for each combination of `Group` and `Round`.  The pipe operator (`%>%`) looks weird when you first see it, but it helps streamline your code.  It takes the output of the previous function and sets it to be the first argument of the next function.  It makes it easy to see that we're taking `df`, grouping by `Group` and `Round`, then summarizing them.

If you *really* want to stick with `plyr`, we can get a solution there too:

```
new.df <- ddply(df, c("Group", "Round"), summarise,
  RV_mean = mean(RV),
  var2_mean = mean(var2) # add a more variables just like this
)
```

We can also work from your list approaches:

```
new.df2 <- ddply(df, .(Group, Round), function(data_subset) { # note alternative way to reference Group and Round
  as.data.frame(llply(data_subset[,c("RV"), drop = FALSE], mean)) # add your variables here
})
```

Note that within `ddply`, I always refer to the subset of the data frame within my function calls, I never refer to `df`.  `df` always refers to the original data frame - not the subset you are trying to work with.

Comment: Thanks Melissa, your first dplyr suggestion worked perfectly.